# Slow wp_posts and wp_postmeta query using Advance Custom Fields

Tags: wp-query, query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, sql

I have a particularly slow query (around 2.2 seconds) getting custom posts (Previews) which are for an event after a certain date and are set as featured (both custom fields stored in wp_postmeta). The query is as below:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2
ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'race_datetime' 
AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'race_datetime'
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATETIME) >= '2018-04-17 17:06' ) 
AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'featured'
AND mt2.meta_value = '1' ) ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'previews'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC
LIMIT 0, 7
```

I've tried looking into the query but I'm no SQL expert and can't seem to work out a way of making the query quicker.

Does anyone have any suggestions on why its so slow and what I could do to improve it?

Comment: meta was never designed to be used when searching for posts. You will need to figure out how to use taxonomies instead, or clear you DB meta from outdated info.

Comment: One really good plugin to help with stuff like this is [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/).